# Loopback to directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, loopback

How do I create a loopback mount which exposes a given directory as a read-only filesystem?  As contrasted with a loopback mount which exposes a file as a filesystem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would imagine that `mount -o bind,ro /some/directory /where/you/want/it/to/be/readonly` should do the trick.

Comment: Just be sure that you're on at least a 2.6.26 kernel or this will silently bind mount with the same options as the original mount-point. See: http://lwn.net/Articles/281157/

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!  And thanks for the caveat, Evan.

Comment: should be able to do `mount --bind -o ro`, too